# Chai should is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have installed Mocha as well as Chai.

In my unit test:

```
import {expect, should} from "chai";

describe("array", function () {
        it("has length of 1", function (done) {
            var arr = ["B"];
            expect(arr).have.lengthOf(1);
            arr.should.have.lengthOf(1);
        });
});
```

`expect` works as expected, but `should` is undefined.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call **`chai.should()`** at the begin of the file to use `should` style.

It will extends each object with a `should` property to start your assertions chain.

You can find more usage examples in [chai documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should).